# HDMI Splitter taking Input from Mac into capture card shutting off a channel

Tags: video-capture, video-processing, hdmi

Hey so what I'm trying to do is take HDMI input (from a computer) to a splitter from which one channel goes to some viewing device (projector or something) while the other channel goes through a capture card into another system for some processing that I'm doing. However, four seconds after I connect my capture card to one of the splitter's output channels the splitter just stops outputting on that channel and essentially shuts that channel off (as seen by the LED on it). However, if I connect a projector to the other output channel it stays working fine on that.

Keep in mind that the input I'm using is from a MacBook Pro. When I switch the input to an Xbox 360 everything works absolutely fine. Also, if I connect the input (MacBook) directly to the system bypassing the splitter it works absolutely fine. Can someone explain what might be going wrong here when I put the splitter in the mix?

Here is the equipment that I'm using:

Splitter: http://www.gofanco.com/2-port-hdmi-splitter-4k-black-splitter2p.html

Capture Card: [https://www.amazon.com/Video-Capture-Device-1080P-Grabber/dp/B01N4SM7H6/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1522955789&sr=8-7&keywords=full+hd+video+capture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N4SM7H6)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this may be an EDID issue. A display or capture device negotiates the best resolution and frame rate via EDID with your graphics card.
Now if you put the splitter in between the EDID based communication can go sideways. 
HDCP could be another reason. Your splitter may not correctly handle or advertise HDCP

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know anyway to fix this resolution negotiation? I tried playing with the resolution output from my laptop to no avail :(

Comment: Also, HDCP wouldn't really be an issue here right because I'm just streaming my laptop's screen?

Comment: For EDID I'd try something like this: https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=14106

Comment: Sometimes laptops use HDCP as default. Anytime you use a streaming service (like Netflix) HDCP is required. I have seen capture cards signaling HDCP support but then failing accepting HDCP content.

Comment: Ok if the splitter didn't accept HDCP then wouldn't connecting the laptop directly to the capture card not have worked? Also, it doesn't seem like the splitter is causing any issues relevant to HDCP in that either because it seems to work if I connect a TV, monitor, etc. to the output end.

Comment: Not in all cases - if the splitter is connected to two outputs - one supports HDCP the other doesn't. The splitter could report HDCP support and then only output the signal to the supported device.